# jQuery - Mark a notification as read

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap and I found a really good looking admin template. This template offers the possibility to show specific notifications at the main navigation. If I click on the notification icon, a small popup appears where I can see the notification.

You can see it here: 
[image]

So I entered the green checkboxes on the left and if a user clicks on a checkbox, the notification is marked as read and dissapears from the notification panel. So far so good my problem is that I solved this solution with PHP and the complete page reloads once I click on the green checkbox. I am now looking for a jQuery solution, so that the page does not need to reload itself once the green checkbox is checked. So if a user clicks on the green checkbox, the notification should disappear without reloading the page.

My current code is:

```
<?php
 <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-navbar'>
    <li>
        <a href='./index.php?func=showsms&id=".$msg["id"][$x]."&sid=$sid' target='_blank' class='clearfix'>
            <div class='col-sm-3'>
                <span class='msg-time'>
                    <a class='btn btn-success btn-xs' href='./index.php?func=$func&read_sms=".$msg["id"][$x]."&sid=$sid' role='button'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-check  bigger-110 icon-only'></i></a>
                </span>
                </span>\
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-9'>
                <a href='#messagebox_".$msg["id"][$x]."' role='button' class='green' data-toggle='modal'>
                    <span class='msg-body'>
                        <span class='msg-title'>
                            <span class='blue'>".$sender["firstname"][0]." ".$sender["lastname"][0].":</span>
                        $msg["smstitle"][$x]
                    </span>

                    <span class='msg-time'>
                        <i class='ace-icon fa fa-clock-o'></i>
                            <span>".date("d.m.Y H:i",$msg["time_created"][$x])."</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
?>
```

Can someone tell me how I need to change the code so that I have the same solution with jQuery effect? I am not good at coding with jQuery. Would be awesome if someone can help me and tell me what my code should look like.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: can you please create an html jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @HarshMakani These are kind of `ajax` solutions for which `jsfiddle` cannot be expected

Comment: That is why i asked for an html version of it.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : FYI Ajax requests can be simulated in jsfiddle

Comment: So, you want to make the message list become mark as "read" once you click it? But use jquery right?

Comment: @ChristophC Yes you can do it with `ajax` and with or without `jquery` too.. I ain't sure how people do it in `php` but if you post your `php` code here, those who know might help you..

Comment: @HendryTanaka YES exactly. I am not sure if I need jQuery or Ajax for that. Just want that it work without reloading the page as it does right now with my PHP solution.

Comment: @CerlinBoss.. May be.. never came across with one till date.. Anyways thank you..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I do not need a PHP solution, that is already working. I am looking for exact the same solution with jQuery or AJAX so that the page does not reload once I click the green checkbox.

Comment: @ChristophC. You need to make call to your `php` method with ajax so that you update your database and send the response back and your `php` method should be modified so as to send proper response back to client..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao so what should the AJAX code look like? If have no idea about ajax programming :(

Comment: `jquery.ajax` will have several options like `url`,`data` etc which you can check it **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

Comment: @ChristophC. try to learn [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method. It work fine for me without refreshing page.

Comment: @HendryTanaka thanks for the link I already looked at this method and tried to understand it but I did not found the solution on how the code should look like to work with my notifications :(

Comment: @HendryTanaka is it possible that you tell me what the code should look like to work with my HTML code?

Comment: @ChristophC. Notification.....are you going to build synchronous website?

Answer (score 3):

What you have written is HTML and not PHP code! I believe there should be a class for changing it to a different colour (read notification). So, what you need to do is:

```
$(".dropdown-menu dropdown-navbar li a").click(function () {
  $(this).closest("li").addClass("read");
  // The above code will make the presentation look read.
  // Now make it really read:
  $.post("notification.php", {id: the_post_id, action: read});
  return false;
});
```

**Note:** I didn't prevent the default action of following the link, because when you follow the link, it will trigger the read action right?

And I hope in PHP, when you render the HTML, you would do:

```
<li class="otherClass newClass type <?php if ($isRead) echo "read"; ?>">
```

Comment: you need ajax solution to stop the page reload.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao maybe you are right. I do not know if that is AJAX or jQuery but the notification must disappear without reloading the page once the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: It is simple jquery. In your ajax response set the notification and in your html, on click of that notification button just add/remove class to clear the notification.

Comment: @HarshMakani can you let me know what my jQuery should look like or is the code from Praveen Kumar already the solution?

Comment: what praveen provided is a true. You just need to clear that "read" class again in your ajax response so that notification icon again display that a new notification has arrived. This is actually be on the fly output.

Comment: @ChristophC. I have explained in my edit. Have a look at the updated post.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you very much. My problem is that I still do not understand the code. What do you mean by "notification.php" and the id? What link should be included there? Also why do I have to echo "read" in my HTML code?